# Reading structured texts in R

Tags: r

Please give me some advice on reading text files similar to the following one in R?

1. Each block is surrounded by a header and a footer.
2. Number of fields of each Block are fixed.
3. A few fields might span several rows.

My questions are

1. Use a list or a data frame to hold the file content?
2. Is any other way to properly parse the file content other than readlines?
3. how to create an empty typed-vector?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your question divides into two parts: (1) how do I read this particular text file format [A: I don't think there's anything better than cooking up your own code using `readLines`, unless this is a standard format that someone else has already dealt with: `library(sos); findFn()` is your friend there ...] and (2) in what kind of a data structure should I store the result? [A: it depends. We would need to know a little bit more about the contents of the fields, etc.]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try that findFn() later.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have read and looked at the many packages mentioned in [R-data](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html)? Apart from that: from what I understand, you need a list of data.frames for your data (each block coinciding with one data.frame).

A better option may be to first split the file into several 'block'-files (preferably with tools outside of R, as these may be better fit for that particular task), and then read the data.frames with standard functions (assuming these comply - you do not give much information on that).

Why would you want to create an empty typed vector? Closest thing is probably a list. But if you think you need one, you may need to rethink.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I am trying to read these blocks first, and then transform several fields into the destination dataframe. Sorry for that empty typed-vector, R language is quite different than programming language.